# Container-Fluid in Mobile

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, bootstrap-4

I have a list like that:

[image]

I open a hidden div to show details about list items like that:

[image]

It's ok for large screen but in mobile info div goes so below. Is it possible  to open info div as %100 (Container-Fluid) under that item in mobile like that:

[image]

If it's possible what is the keywords or can you show an example? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created a sample where you need to create two locations with the same div contents, one for mobile (`.mobile-content`) and one for desktop (`.desktop-content`).

The way you style it is **when the mobile is visible, the desktop is hidden** and vice versa. You can hide and show element using the Bootstraps 4 `.d-x-none` and `.d-x-block`.

The only thing left is you have to implement the click mechanism when you click on the circles......

**Example (view this in full page):**

```css
.main-box {
 text-align:center;
}

.circle{
  flex-basis:33%;
}

.circle img{
  background:pink;
  border-radius: 50%;
  max-width:100%;
}

.mobile-content{
  flex-basis:100%;

}

.desktop-content{
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="main-box container-fluid d-flex justify-content-center flex-wrap flex-lg-nowrap">
  
  <div class="circle px-2"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/200x200/4d204d/ffffff" /></div>
  <div class="circle px-2"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/200x200/4d204d/ffffff" /></div>
  <div class="circle px-2"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/200x200/4d204d/ffffff" /></div>
  <div class="mobile-content p-2 d-lg-none">
    <p>description comes here</p>
  </div>
  <div class="circle px-2"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/200x200/4d204d/ffffff" /></div>
  <div class="circle px-2"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/200x200/4d204d/ffffff" /></div>
  
</div>


 <div class="desktop-content p-4 d-none d-lg-block">
    <p>description comes here</p>
  </div>
```

Comment: But i don't want to hide it. Iwant to show it under relative item div as %100.

Comment: Does your detail divs need to be visible on all platforms? Or just mobile?

Comment: Should be visible on all but i want it close to related item.

Comment: To clarify you want to show your detail divs on all platforms, When on desktop view, when use click on each list the detail will show up below all the list and you have to option to close it. Once you get into mobile you want the detail div to show up in the middle (in between 3rd and 4th list) instead of bottom. Am I right?

Comment: Also please provide html and css in your post so I can modify from there straightaway.

Comment: Yes. After breakpoint, a second or third row is created. I want to show first row items details between under first row. But in fact there is only one bootstrap row. Maybe i can use relative/absolute for all items and details.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157281/discussion-between-vincent1989-and-laconic).

Answer (score 0):

In bootstrap 4, for equal columns in all devices try like this

```html
<div class="row">
<div class="col">
      1 of n
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      1 of n
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      1 of n
    </div>
       .....
      <div class="col">
      n of n
    </div>
</div>
```

```css
#circle {
 width: 50px;
 height: 50px;
 background: red;
 -moz-border-radius: 50%;
 -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
 border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row">
        <div class="col" id="circle">
          
        </div>
        <div class="col" id="circle">
          
        </div>
         <div class="col" id="circle">
          
        </div>
         <div class="col" id="circle">
          
        </div>
         <div class="col" id="circle">
          
        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: I guess i'm misunderstood. I still want to bootstrap breakpoints. But when there is a second row, item detail (gray area) should seem under related item's row.But in fact it's not a row. So i asked if it's possible. :/

Btw, thanks for your effort.

Comment: No thats not possible with your html structure(assuming its bs4 tabs structure). or update your code or add fiddle

Comment: it's just bootstrap grid. One row and col-2

Comment: you can implement like 3 in one row and 2 in another row. then you will get expected output